# qt-creator and msvc can't add a (static) library

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt-creator, msvc12

I have a 3rd party (closed source) static library (.lib) written in C, with a C++ compatible header and a very simple C++ test program.

After creating a new project in Qt-creator, I tried to compile the program and link to the static library, but the linker cannot resolve the symbols: "Unresolved external symbol", error LNK2019.

I am using Qt 5.3 with the compiler from VisualC++ 2013 Express (which I think is MSVC12), and the .pro file used in Qt-creator is the following:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

LIBS += -L"C:/Users/myuser/myproject" -lsomelib

SOURCES += main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    somelib.h
```

assuming that in `C:\Users\myuser\myproject` there are the following two files:

- libsomelib.lib
- somelib.h

I am not sure about what to provide in the `-l` flag, so I tried with `libsomelib.lib`, `libsomelib` and `somelib` as I would do in Linux, but every combination was unsuccessful.

This is my first time using MSVC from Qt-creator (not that I have much experience with it), so I cannot really understand the linking command issued by qt-creator, which includes manifest files that I do not know, and - apparently - no files or libraries are listed explicitly in the command:

```
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\myproject.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\myproject.exe @C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\myproject.exe.4260.531.jom
```

Note that if I do not use qmake and compile this example by hand using `cl` and `link`, the program links just fine. To achieve this, I use the commands:

```
cl /MT /EHsc /c main.cpp 
link /LIBPATH:C:\Users\myuser\myproject libsomelib.lib main.obj  /out:test.exe
```

How can I fix that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe use backslashes in "C:/Users/myuser/myproject"?

Comment: @vahancho qmake documentation says that It would fix that automatically, but I also tried that and it's no use :(

Comment: It is not necessary to specify the .lib extension, nor the lib prefix (on UNIX platforms). So in your case "-llibsomelib" is correct. That dont solve the problem but only to tell you about it.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I managed to compile the code using MSVC.

I tried to reproduce the compilation on Qt-Creator but without success; also tried to export a qmake project from VS using the Qt Add-in, but the issue persist in qt creator. So I'm giving up and continue to use VS to compile.